# One word for a person who repeats the same issue over and over again

Tags: single-word-requests

How to name a person in one word who likes to repeat the things s/he has done or said or whatever, over and over again in every occasion. E.g. Ms Somebody always repeats the same incident which occurred 15 years ago, in every party/ meeting, which becomes kind of irritating after a couple of times, but s/he still enjoys repeating it. Like S/he visited the Bahamas in 2001, and in every occasion we meet (s/he is a relative of mine) at least once a year, he keeps repeating (in details) the visit to the Bahamas, which is quite annoying after two decades. S/He is .......

Comment: Boring (you don't need to hear it again)? Fixated (she can't let it go)? Forgetful (she doesn't remember she's already told you)? We probably need some more detail here.

Comment: @ Andrew Leach, Thank you, but the way s/he tells it, it feels like bragging. s/he is like fixated type, determined to repeat the same stuff and enjoy doing so

Comment: Please **[edit] your question** to include all information which might help people come to an answer. Don't bury clarifications in comments. It might actually be useful to include examples of what is told, and their manner, and more of how it affects you.

Answer (score 3):

Not one word solutions, but just in case:

"She keeps *harping on* about something."

"She's a *broken record* about something."

Or one word, but probably not the right meaning (keeps talking about uninteresting things):

"She's a *windbag*."

"She's a *chatterbox*."

Comment: To 'hark on' is to 'to urge on with encouraging cries'. Did you mean 'harp on', 'to dwell wearisomely upon in speech or writing.'? (both per OED.)

Comment: You're right, @Spagirl, I'll change it! Sorry...

Comment: No worries, it's a confusion that seems to be on the rise generally. :)